# Como poner la siguiente y anterior cancion en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola estoy haciendo un reproductor de musica en android studio y quesiera saber como puedo pasar a la siguiente cancion al darle al boton Siguiente lo mismo en el caso al momento de regresar

Lo estoy haciendo con un listview y al momento de darle click a una cancion esta se reproduzca, actualmente eso si me funciona el problema es con los botones de siguiente y anterior no funcionan como deberian.

Estas canciones se encuentran en mi carpeta raw

Aqui esta mi codigo estan son mis variables y mi metodo onCreate

```
 ListView listaCanciones;
List<String> list;
ListAdapter adapter;

MediaPlayer mp;

int posicion = 0;
Button play_pause, btn_repetir;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_explorador);

    play_pause = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlay_Pause);
    listaCanciones = findViewById(R.id.lv);

    list = new ArrayList<>();

    Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++){
        list.add(fields[i].getName());
    }


    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.list_view_configuracion, list);
    listaCanciones.setAdapter(adapter);

    listaCanciones.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(mp != null ){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }

            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(i), "raw", getPackageName());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Explorador.this, resID);
            mp.start();
            play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausa);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Este es mi metodo Play y pause que me funciona correctamente

```
 //Metodo para el boton PlayPause
public void play_pause(View view){
    if (mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.pause();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reproducir);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pausa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        mp.start();
        play_pause.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pausa);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reproduciendo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Y estos son mis metodos siguiente y anterior

```
//Metodo para boton Siguiente
public void Siguiente(View view){
    if (posicion < list.size() -1){

        if(mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
            posicion++;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(posicion), "raw", getPackageName());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Explorador.this, resID);
            mp.start();
        }
        else {
            posicion++;
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay más canciones", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

//Metodo para boton Anterior
public void Anterior(View view){
    if (posicion >= 1){

        if (mp.isPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
            posicion--;
            int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(list.get(posicion), "raw", getPackageName());
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(Explorador.this, resID);
            mp.start();

        }else{
            posicion--;

        }

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No hay más canciones", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema se muestra algo en el LogCat? agrega esta información por favor, revisar [ask].

Comment: No me muestra ningun problema pero al darle click al boton siguiente no lo hace desde la posicion actual sino que desde la primera posicion

Comment: te muestra el toast ""No hay más canciones"" @EduardoNoyola